# Directive doesn't fire on tab selection/page scrolling in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

What I want to do is to display a placeholder image before the real image fully loaded. And I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791174/how-to-show-a-placeholder-image-before-the-real-image-is-downloaded). I am using exactly the same code as the accepted answer. This answer works pretty good for normal situation.

However, my case is a little bit different. On my page, I have two tabs. I'm using `ion-slide-box` for the tab selection. And I load different content when user switch the tabs. Under each tab, it's a long list of items. Each item has a image, on which I implement this placeholder image display method. User is able to scroll down to see more items. So when user scroll down, I'll load more items.

Here is a peek of my code, it's simplified:

HTML:

```
<div class="tab-bar">
<div class="tab-option" ng-class="(slide == 0 ? 'active' : '') ng-click="setSlide(0)">
    Tab 1
</div>
<div class="tab-option" ng-class="(slide == 1 ? 'active' : '') ng-click="setSlide(1)">
    Tab 2
</div>
```

```
<ion-view>
<ion-content>
    <div class="list">
        <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" active-slide="slide">
            <ion-slide>
                <ion-list ng-repeat="item in items">
                    My content and Image Here
                    <img hires="{{item.realImageUrl}}" src="placeholderImage.jpg"/>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
                <ion-list ng-repeat="item in items">
                    My content and Image Here
                    <img hires="{{item.realImageUrl}}" src="placeholderImage.jpg"/>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

In my controller(this is simplified a lot, I don't want to bother with un-related code):

```
slideHasChanged = function (index) {
    getMoreItems(); //get more data from server here.
};
```

This is the directive:

```
app.directive('hires', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { hires: '@' },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('link fired');
            element.one('load', function() {
                console.log('load fired');
                element.attr('src', scope.hires);
            });
        }
     };
});
```

The issue is, the placeholder image works good for the first time I come to this page and load the first batch of items. But whenever I need to scroll down, or switch tab, the placeholder image doesn't work anymore. The behavior is that, it's always showing placeholder image, the real image is not displayed after it's fully downloaded/loaded.

I wonder is it because this method only works when you load a page? And doesn't work because switching tab or scrolling down doesn't trigger page loading? If I want this to work for my situation, what change is needed on this method?

I put two debugging messages in my directives, I log out 'link fired' and 'load fired'. Turns out that the link function is fired correctly, it's just the `element.one('load', function())` is not fired. Is it that the scope somehow doesn't match? Any thoughts?

I've been trying the code a lot. And actually sometimes it works, when I switch tab or scroll down. But most time doesn't work. This is confusing, I don't know why it works sometimes.

Comment: You'll get a lot more help if you post the relevant code and HTML.

Comment: @MikeFeltman I just updated my question, added some code.

Comment: I think the curly braces around item.realImageUrl are unnecessary. That may not be related to the issue at all, but I'd try removing them just to check. Did you create the directive as well?

Comment: @MikeFeltman yes I created the directive. It's exactly the same as the answer in the link in my question. curly braces is the way to bind data in angular and can't be removed.

Comment: `element.one('load'` i guess you don't have the same typo in your true code but i prefer to be sure -> `element.on('load'`

Comment: @Walfrat No it's not a typo, it is `one`, otherwise it'll keep triggering the code.

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know about that, did you inspect the HTML for the src value ? WHen the thab is hidden, when it's displayed after tab click to see what is happening ?

Comment: @Walfrat I inspected it. The src is still placeholder image. but hires is the real image url. It's just not substituted. Means somehow the directive is not fired, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got the right way to do it, just change the `link` function of directive to this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.hires != element.attr('src')) {
        element.attr('src', scope.hires);
    }
}
```

Get rid of `element.one`. That's the reason it only works once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track and have to probably try to tie into when the item actually becomes visible. There's a directive for this called InView available here: https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview. I have a somewhat similar issue that I have this bookmarked for, but it's pretty far down my to-do list.

Comment: I'm new to angular. The github project you provided has too many unrelated information and it's hard for me to extract useful information. If you can provide the solution for my case based on the reference it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your directive:

```
app.directive('hires', function() {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('hires', function(value) {
        element.attr({
            'src': value
        });
    });      
  };
});
```

Using the $observe here acts much like the ng-src would.