# async loading img on angularjs app

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a simple and good way to load my photos on my Angularjs app.
for exemple, I had, a img

```
<img ng-src="{{myPathToImg}}">
```

and I want to display another img ( svg spinner ) like somes point who mooves
during the image download.
I think I have to use a directive, but I don't know how to load with async my img

Comment: Are you asking about how to render a placeholder image while another image is loading?

Comment: I think this
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984183/best-way-to-preload-images-with-angular-js
will help you!

Comment: you can default value of `myPathToImg` to loader and then populate it again with actual image. or use `ng-if` / `ng-show`